# Dynamodb put_item qps

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

Does dynamodb limit the qps of put_item action?

I tried to migrate some records from json files to dynamodb by using aiobotocore which is an asynchronous wrapper of boto3.

By using method put_item, it's hard to reach the throughtput.

After change methods from put_item to batch_write_item, it's easily up to the write capacity.

```
# Codes like this
import aiobotocore
import asyncio

resources = iter([])     
throughput = 1000
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
dydb = aiobotocore.get_session().create_client('dynamodb')


async def put_item(cli, item, table_name):
    await cli.put_item(TableName=table_name, Item=item)


async def batch_write_item(cli, items):
    await cli.batch_write_item(RequestItems=items)


async def test_put_item(resource, table_name):
    for item in resource:
        await put_item(dydb, item, table_name)


async def test_batch_write_item(resource):
    batch = []
    for item in resource:
        if len(batch) > 24:
            await batch_write_item(dydb, batch)
            batch = []
        else:
            batch.append(item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # put item
    tasks = [test_put_item(resource) for _ in range(throughput)]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))

    # batch write
    # tasks = [test_batch_write_item(resource) for _ in range(throughput // 25)]
    # loop.run_until_complete(*tasks)
```